# Log traffic coming in to a specific URL on my Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: rest, powershell, iis, server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have IIS setup and hosting an application which can be contacted via an API. To connect to this API you have to send credentials to a certain URL. For example:

```
$data = {
  username : test,
  password : test
}
$url = 'https://myapi.com/api/authorize/oauth/token'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Headers $authHeader -Body $data
```

My question is, can I capture the data incoming from a certain URL, specifically the one above? I would like to get IIS or write a script to save all logs when clients contact this URL.

Answer (score 0):

Right, managed to solve this.

TLDR; Add Advanced logging and filter by URL in the definition.

You need to add Advanced Logging : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7211

- From here, go to your site in IIS, and select Advanced Logging
- Create a new definition
- Edit Filter
- Add Expression

  - Field = URI-Stem
  - Operator = Equals
  - Value = specific URL you wish to filter by
- Apply changes

Now you will have logging when a user accesses your site/API via a certain URL.

Default logging directory : C:\inetpub\logs\AdvancedLogs\DEFAULT WEB SITE

More info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-log-filtering

Remember; by default the log files are owned by the SYSTEM. They need to be owned by the Administrator. To change this, right click > properties > security > advanced > Change (next to the owner) > advanced > choose Administrator (may need to authorize yourself)